# Not all polygons removed when cutting from vector layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, vector

I have created ten polygons representing lakes on a vector layer, and I am trying to cut them from an imported and re-projected vector layer of administrative districts. When I use the 'Cut with polygon from another layer' feature, only nine lakes are removed. The last one overlaps two districts but is not cut from either of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a closer look at my problem lake outline, and found that there were two points crossed over, effectively creating a very small loop on my geometry (QGIS highlighted this with a green cross when I zoomed in). I rearranged the two points and retried the cut using the same process and all polygons now cut correctly.